# Using XML PATH to manipulate row data when grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, winforms, pivot

In a sql query I'm trying to do two things.

I have a table `Attendance` like this

***TABLE***

```
EID |  PID  |      In_Time     |     Out_Time      | Shift 
__________________________________________________________
100 |  S001 | 2014-05-01 07:10 |  2014-05-01 19:20 |   D
100 |  S001 | 2014-05-04 07:00 |  2014-05-04 19:00 |   D
100 |  S001 | 2014-05-04 19:00 |  2014-05-05 07:00 |   N
```

EID -EmployeeID

PID -PointID (Location)

D - Day Shift

N - Night Shift

When I group by all fields except Shift, (When grouping only the `DatePart` of `In_Time` fields will be taken)  I want to get this

***INTERMEDIATE STEP***

```
EID |  DAY | Shift |
___________________
100 |  01  |  D    |
100 |  04  |  D/N  |
```

Finally I want to `PIVOT` this to get following result

***EXPECTED FINAL RESULT***

```
EmployeeID | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04  |
__________________________________
100        |  D | _  | _  | D/N |
```

I Use following query in this purpose but I'm getting slightly different result.

```
SELECT EID AS EmployeeID, [1],[2],[3],[4] 
FROM (

SELECT 
  EID, datepart(dd,in_time) as [DAY],
  STUFF((
    SELECT '/ ' + Shift  
    FROM Attendance  
    WHERE ([in_time] = Results.[in_time] ) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS Shifts 
FROM Attendance Results 
WHERE EID = '100' AND PID ='C002' 
GROUP BY EID , in_time
) AS SourceTable 

 PIVOT
 (
 MAX (Shifts ) 
 FOR [DAY] IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4])
 ) AS PivotTable
```

This is the result of the query

```
   EmployeeID | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04  |
   ________________________________
   100        |  D | _  | _  | N/N |
```

So something wrong in my query and could you pleas help me to sort this out? What's I'm missing in this query? Do you know any better way to do this?

**EDIT:** I just realized that the above code works well as long as the Attendance table contains records relevant to a single employee and a single Point (PID).

If the above table has details of several employees (EIDs) who works at different locations (PIDs) then the out put is wrong. So I see the code is not consistent but my knowledge in sql seems not enough to sort this out with out a help :(

Comment: What about Out_Time = 2014-05-05 07:00. It is not displayed in your desired result. Are u only looking at the in time as the employee's working day?

Comment: @ Jithin Shaji, Yes, The shift is belongs to day of the In_Time. So I dont want to get Out_Time. Out_Time will only be used to categorize shifts

Comment: I removed some unwanted stuff to make it more simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below answer may help you. The SQL looks lengthy, but the logic is simple, just grouping D and N data and finally joining. may be you can work from this.

```
DECLARE @Lu_Dt table
(id int identity(1,1),Dt Date)
INSERT INTO @Lu_Dt VALUES('2014-05-01'),
('2014-05-02'),('2014-05-03'),
('2014-05-04'),('2014-05-05')

DECLARE @tab table
(EID int,PID varchar(15),In_Time datetime,Out_Time datetime,[Shift] Char(1))
INSERT INTO @tab Values
(100,'S001','2014-05-01 07:10','2014-05-01 19:20','D'),
(100,'S001','2014-05-04 07:00','2014-05-04 19:00','D'),
(100,'S001','2014-05-04 19:00','2014-05-05 07:00','N')

SELECT * FROM @tab
```

[image]

```
DECLARE @refTab table
(id int identity(1,1),EID int, Dt Date,[shift] varchar(3))

INSERT INTO @refTab

SELECT      Lu.EID,Lu.Dt,coalesce(LU1.[Flag],LU2.[Flag]) [shift]
FROM        (SELECT *,100 EID FROM @Lu_Dt) Lu
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT D.EID,D.In_Time,'D/N' [Flag]
            FROM    (SELECT EID,CAST(In_Time AS DATE) In_Time FROM @tab Where Shift = 'D') D
            JOIN    (SELECT EID,CAST(In_Time AS DATE) In_Time FROM @tab Where Shift = 'N') N 
            ON      D.In_Time = N.In_Time AND D.EID = N.EID) LU1 ON Lu.Dt = LU1.In_Time
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT CAST(In_Time AS DATE) In_Time,'D' [Flag] FROM @tab Where Shift = 'D') LU2 ON Lu.Dt = LU2.In_Time
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT CAST(In_Time AS DATE) In_Time,'N' [Flag] FROM @tab Where Shift = 'N') LU3 ON Lu.Dt = LU3.In_Time

SELECT * FROM @refTab
```

[image]

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT EID,Dt,[shift] from @refTab) As src 
PIVOT
(MAX([shift]) for Dt in 
    (   [2014-05-01],
        [2014-05-02],
        [2014-05-03],
        [2014-05-04],
        [2014-05-05])) AS PivotTable;
```

**Result**

[image]

As there is a lot of hard coding, it cant be used as such.Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped. If you don't mind, could you explain the second part of your code (Starts with `INSERT INTO @refTab`...) will be helpful a lot.

Comment: I saved the result into a temp table @refTab, so that writing the PIVOT statement will look less complex.